# Dynamic Array Bidimensional in vb.net

Tags: php, vb.net

i want to work with array in vb.net, but i cant, now I am more familiar with php, javascript, and for example in php i can work with `array_push` for add a new index. here example

```
$myarray=[];
array_push($myarray,array("AAAA","BBB"));
```

and next i can call it with the index

```
echo $myarray[0][1];  //result: BBB
```

but in vb.net i dont know how i can do it??, i try with this

```
dim myArray(0,1) as string
redim myArray(myArray.length-1,1)

myArray(myArray.length-1,0)
myArray(myArray.length-1,1)
```

but i no have the same result

Comment: You want a `List(Of List (Of T))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @SLaks you have reason, here is the solution for other person

```
       Dim myarray As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))()
      myarray.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"ID", "AAA"}})
myarray.Add(New Dictionary(Of String, String)() From {{"value", "BBB"}})
```

And the for each

```
For Each subArray As Dictionary(Of String, String) In myArray
    Dim id As String = subArray("ID")
    Dim value As String = subArray("value")
Next
```